# CSS doesn't page properly

Tags: css, http

I have an html file that I want to use to produce some product tags that will fit a standard 3.5" x 2" business card format.

It uses 3 premade images as backgrounds to fill out 3 div's to specific sizes.
http://www.orcasoul.com/images/bowls/fullpage.jpg is 8.5" x 11", the size of the sheet of paper.
http://www.orcasoul.com/images/bowls/pagebox.jpg is 7" x 10", the size of the area on the paper that holds the cards.
http://www.orcasoul.com/images/bowls/cardbox.jpg is 3.5" x 2", the size of the individual cards.

I have styles for the div for each page image, and 2 div's for the cardbox - left and right.

The style code:

```
        <style>
        html, body {height:100%;}
        div.fullpage
        {
            position:relative;
            width:8.5in;
            height:11in;
            background-image:url("http://www.orcasoul.com/scw/fullpage.jpg");
            background-position:center center;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
        div.pagecard
        {
            position:relative;
            top:0px;
            width:7in;
            height:10in;
            margin-left:0.75in;
            margin-right:0.75in;
            margin-top:0.5in;
            margin-bottom:0.5in;
            background-image:url("http://www.orcasoul.com/scw/pagebox.jpg");
            background-position:center center;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }

        div.card-block-left
        {
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            width:3.5in;
            height:2in;
            background-image:url("http://www.orcasoul.com/scw/cardBox.jpg");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
        div.card-block-right
        {
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            width:3.5in;
            height:2in;
            background-image:url("http://www.orcasoul.com/scw/cardBox.jpg");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
        p.single_record
        {
            page-break-after: always
        }
    </style>
```

In  I have the following code:

```
    <body>
    <div class="fullpage">
        <div class="pagecard">
            <div class="card-block-left">
                <img class="image-bowl" src="http://www.orcasoul.com/scw/MyrtleTiBurl07-005.jpg" />
                <div class="info-box">
                    <p>10½" Tiger Myrtle Burl Bowl</p>
                    <p>MyrtleTiBurl07-005</p>
                    <p class="text-index">Product #337</p>
                </div>
                <div class="price-box">
                    <p>$120</p>
                </div>
                <div class="link-box"> 
                    <p>http://www.splinterscraftworks.us/</p>
                </div>
                <img class="logo" src="BowlPhotos/SCW_Logo.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-block-right">
                <img class="image-bowl" src="http://www.orcasoul.com/scw/MyrtleTiBurl07-005.jpg" />
                <div class="info-box">
                    <p>10½" Tiger Myrtle Burl Bowl</p>
                    <p>MyrtleTiBurl07-005</p>
                    <p class="text-index">Product #337</p>
                </div>
                <div class="price-box">
                    <p>$120</p>
                </div>
                <div class="link-box"> 
                    <p>http://www.splinterscraftworks.us/</p>
                </div>
                <img class="logo" src="BowlPhotos/SCW_Logo.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="single_record"></p>
    <div>
</body>
```

The actual code repeats the  code for 9 pages, to see if everything lines up properly...

It doesn't.

The left to right alignment is perfect, as is the first page of cards (10 in all).

But after a page or so, there seems to be a drift downward on the page and the last page bleeds onto the next one.

The

is supposed to go to the top of the next page.

I have uploaded the HTML to http://www.orcasoul.com/images/bowls/testtags.html

This should give me the exact pages - why doesn't it?

Comment: Make your question short

Comment: I've seen much longer, and I could have posted the entire code - over 9 pages...

Answer (score 0):

Your first page is containing 10 cards, which is OK for your layout, but the next pages only contain 2 cards. 
With your 10 inches fixed heights on your page divs, you get that big white space.

Comment: I've added all the pages now...try it now. Use the print preview.

Comment: I seem to have good results by adding *page-break-after: always;* to your .fullpage divs.

Comment: That should be in the p.single_record class...it's called at the end of the <p class="single_record"></p> statement at the end of each page.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But by adding that same declaration to your fullpage divs, my print layout was good. Anyways, it makes more sense to me to put it there, and you can remove your .single_record ps.

Comment: OK, is that AFTER the fullpage div is closed, and just before the next fullpage div?

Comment: I changed the <div class="fullfile" line to <div class="fullpage" style="page-break-after: always;">...now the 2nd page is empty and the rest seem to lack the top spacing...I'll up load that change in a few minutes.

Comment: OK, I changed the <div class="fullpage" line to <div class="fullpage" style="page-break-after: always;">, and also made the fullpage non positional...it's uploaded now. And now it skips every page, and the pages past the first one are printing the cards too high. It's probably in the settings for the placement for the pagecard class...